# Assigning a PointAnimation to an ellipse

Tags: wpf

I want to animate some ellipses with a SplinePointAnimationWithKeyframes, but I can't figure out which target property I must set to the story board:

```
    StoryBoard.SetTargetProperty(splineAnimation, Canvas.???);
```

thanks for you're help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Examples section in [PointAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.pointanimation.aspx) for how to animate the `Center` property of an `EllipseGeometry`.

If you want to animate let's say the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` of an Ellipse element, you would need to have two separate animations in your Storyboard. The same is true for e.g. animating the `X` and `Y` properties of a [TranslateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx).